# Does the process of extraction of chondroitin sulfate change the molecular structure of the bovine source it is extracted from?

Tags: molecular-structure

I have been prescribed Chondoritin Sulfate for my joints.  For religious reasons, I don't have bovine.   Hence my question.  Does the process of extraction of chondroitin sulfate change the molecular structure of the bovine source it is extracted from?  If it changes, then it's not bovine anymore and hence okay for me to consume.

There is a [paper here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0021925818563614?token=1A448B3942F61D5EA57D3B73A6345D97A1A485D2CF5CA1C666BCC8018EBFF529A38AD26B95FD2BC1284EEAA80A88477D&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220221034743) that explains the extraction process in detail.

It's too technical for me, but would be grateful if a chemist could [read it](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0021925818563614?token=1A448B3942F61D5EA57D3B73A6345D97A1A485D2CF5CA1C666BCC8018EBFF529A38AD26B95FD2BC1284EEAA80A88477D&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220221034743) and verify if the molecular structure of the source is changed.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Short answer: bovine chondroitin comes from cows. There are other sources (marine) that might work. Have you considered a [vegan/vegetarian supplement containing chondroitin](https://www.devanutrition.com/vegan-glucosamine-msm-chondroitin-plus.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your response @ToddMinehardt!  Vegan supplements are indeed an option.  However, though it comes from bovine source, if the extraction process changes the molecular structure, then it's no longer "bovine".  

Therefore posting [this paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0021925818563614?token=1A448B3942F61D5EA57D3B73A6345D97A1A485D2CF5CA1C666BCC8018EBFF529A38AD26B95FD2BC1284EEAA80A88477D&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220221034743) here.  Does this process change the molecular structure?